# How can I send data from thread to Gtk app?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, gtk3

I have the following code:

```py
import socket
from queue import Queue
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
import threading


HOST = ''  # Listen on all available network interfaces
PORT = 5000  # Arbitrary port number

def socket_server(queue):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    print('Listening for incoming connections...')
    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print(f'Received data from client: {data.decode()}')
        queue.put(data.decode())
        client_socket.close()


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="GTK App")
        self.set_default_size(400, 300)
        self.label = Gtk.Label(label="Welcome to the GTK App!")
        self.add(self.label)

    def set_label_text(self):
        text = self.queue.get()
        self.label.set_text(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    socket_thread = threading.Thread(target=socket_server, args=(q,))
    socket_thread.start()
    win = MyWindow(q)
    win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

The programs basically runs a socket server on a thread and a gtk app on the main thread. What I'm trying to do is to, every time the socket receives a request, to send the message recived to the gtk app and the gtk app update his label with that message. I'm trying to do it with `queue` but I'm stuck on `self.queue.get()` because I can't figure how to watch for messages without block GTK Main loop. How can I watch for queue messages without blocking the main gtk loop, are there better approaches to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you add an item in the queue, call `GLib.idle_add` from the child thread to have a function execute in the main thread.

this is mentioned in the [PyGObject threads documentation](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/threading.html#threads)

```py
def socket_server(queue):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    print('Listening for incoming connections...')
    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print(f'Received data from client: {data.decode()}')
        queue.put(data.decode())
        client_socket.close()
        GLib.idle_add(win.update_gui_from_queue)  # this line


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    ...
    def update_gui_from_queue(self):
        q.get()
        # do what you want with the data
        return False  # to stop repetition
```